# VBA Excel : Subroutine work but if called, It no longer works

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there Stuck with a `CALL` problem

I created a subroutine called `Daily_Proto_1`
It copies data from the user form to my worksheet : This is the code:

```
Public Sub Daily_Proto_1()
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("DailyRep")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

'Adds the TextBox1 into Col A & Last Blank Row
'Adds the TextBox2 into Col B & Last Blank Row
'Adds the ComboBox1 into Col C & Last Blank Row
'Ect.

    ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Text
    ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = TextBox2.Text
    ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox1.Text
    ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = TextBox3.Text
    ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox2.Text
    ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox3.Text

End Sub
```

Now in my User form I have a submit button that should call this routine as stipulated below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call Module1.Daily_Proto_1

End Sub
```

The reason for this is so that I can include this in another button, but will have some additional instructions.
When I run the code under the `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` it runs perfectly, however when i move it to the Public Procedure, it gives me the following error:
[image: Error Message]

When I click on debug it takes me to the first line 
[image: VBA code]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a name of your userform prior to TextBox1. For instance

```
 ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
```

Or rather use

```
with UserForm1

end with
```

and dots beforre control names.

Comment: AWESOME!!, it worked, basically all i did was change

`Public Sub Daily_Proto_1()`
`Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet`
to
`Public Sub Daily_Proto_1()`
`With UserForm1`
`Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet`

then inserted the `Userform1.` to all the texboxes and comboboxes.
Worked Like a Dream!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to stipulate the name of your userform before textbox1.text.

```
ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = UserForm1.textbox1.text
```

(replace **Userform1** with the name of your userform)